# How to install camlp4 pre-processor in Cygwin / Windows?

Tags: ocaml, opam

I'm trying to build OPAM within **Cygwin** in Windows 8. Here is the error information during the configure stage:

> configure: error: You must install the Camlp4 pre-processor. On some
>   operating systems, these are separate packages from the main OCaml
>   compiler, such as camlp4-extra on Debian.

I've searched cygwin repository using keywords "caml" and installed all the packages provided; however, the configuration still shows this error message. How can I install this Camlp4 pre-processor?

Comment: As an update; OPAM is supposed to work on Windows now (as of a week or two ago).

Answer (score 1):

[I don't think OPAM works with windows quite yet](https://github.com/OCamlPro/opam/issues/246). I've installed it on OSX and Linux and love it. On windows, though, there is a compilation error with `unix_waitpid`. This is because `ocp-build/ocp-build.boot` is a binary packaged with the OPAM source that requires the `unix_waitpid` instead of the `win_waitpid` function. I'm not exactly sure why they did this. But, after that their could be other issues.

Regarding the camlp4, running `setup.exe` of cygwin, I was easily able to find `ocaml-camlp4` under interpreters. Depending on the tool-chain, I found it easy enough to just use the [mingw binaries](http://protz.github.com/ocaml-installer/) found through the [ocaml website](http://ocaml.org).

Comment: Thank you for your answer and for the valuable information you provided. I have tried to search cygwin running setup.exe, there might be something wrong with my cygwin installation, unfortunately, I cannot get ocaml-camlp4. It is sad news that OPAM doesn't work with Windows. ---I believe it is an important tool for install packages for ocaml, without this convient tool, the ocaml support in windows is incomplete. A little sad for windows users who are out of luck.

Comment: OPAM should normally work well under cygwin (well at least is should at least compile)

Comment: @Thomas, I've tried compiling and ran into the issue mentioned above, could you elaborate on my issue?

Answer (score 1):

As long as OPAM doesn't work on windows, you can try GODI ([windows port](http://wodi.forge.ocamlcore.org/)). It has basic windows support and you can install the most common packages through it.

Comment: Thank you. I've tried to install WODI several times; however, the installation faild: Downloading and installing various cygwin packages failed : -(

Comment: The cygwin website was down during the last days, therefore a normal installation was not possible (the installer needs ressources from cygwin.com). Their infastructure seems to be online now so everything should work again.

If it still fails at this stage, you can install cygwin yourself manually (via http://cygwin.com/setup.exe) and then install wodi to this cygwin environment. You just need to make, that all necessary cygwin packages are installed: preselected ones and rlwrap, cpio, make, bc, patch and mingw64-x86_64-gcc-core (64-bit)/ mingw64-i686-gcc-core (32-bit),